# Turning a random.random() result into a list - Python

Tags: python, list, typeerror

I'm trying to create a list that pulls ten random real numbers between 30 and 35 and prints them out on a list.  When I run the below code I get the following error:

> TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable.

Here's the code:

```
lis = list(range(10))
random.seed(70)
for i in range(0, len(lis)):
    randreal = (random.random()*5 + 30)
    lis = list(randreal)
    print(lis)
```

I feel like I'm missing something obvious.
When I run the code without

```
lis=list(randreal)
print(lis)
```

I get the results I want, just not in a list.   Also I'm trying to do this without random.uniform

Comment: What is `lis = list(randreal)` supposed to do?

Comment: In my mind it was supposed to build a list that looked like this [34.54884618961936, etc].  With your suggestion below its now looking like this:  [34.54884618961936, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] and the next random float with the 1,2,3,4,etc

Comment: after the first iteration, yes. But it will keep assigning one element at a time and at the end, all elements will be random.

Comment: The final output is `[34.54884618961936, 31.470395203793395, 32.297169396656095, 30.681793552717807, 34.97530360173135, 30.773219981037737, 33.36969776732032, 32.990127772708405, 33.57311858494461, 32.052629620057274]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first created list `lst` [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]. This is unnecessary. Then you are trying to overwrite this list `lst` with new list `list(randreal)` which throws error, because its not valid list constructor

You can either start with empty list and append every random number you created:

```
lis = []
random.seed(70)
for i in range(10):
    randreal = (random.random()*5 + 30)
    lis.append(randreal)
print(lis)
```

or overwrite each value of original list with new random value

```
lis = list(range(10))
random.seed(70)
for i in range(0, len(lis)):
    randreal = (random.random()*5 + 30)
    lis[i] = randreal
print(lis)
```

Comment: your second suggestion did the trick.  I tried creating the empty list but it kept just printing an empty list.  you've been a big help.  I love the fast responses.

Comment: Looking at others answers I'm really surprised you accepted mine. Others suggested using list comprehension one liner. As I mentioned, creating list of 10 elements and then overwriting every element is quite Unnecessary.

Comment: I am under constraints and had to do it without using anything but random.random() and random.seed(70).  I originally used random.uniform(30,35) and got my preferred results.  The biggest part that I wasn't understanding was that I needed to index randreal into the already existing list.  Also I'm VERY new at python.  So list comprehension hasn't even been in the same sentence for me yet.

Answer (score 6):

You write:

```
lis = list(randreal)
```

But `list(..)` is here a constructor. The constructor looks for an iterable object (another list, a set, a dictionary, a generator, etc.) that it can turn into a list. A floating point is *not* iterable, so it can not construct a list for that. It will thus error.

One way to solve it is to **assign to an index of the list `lis`**:

```
lis = [0] * 10
random.seed(70)
for i in range(0, len(lis)):
    randreal = (random.random()*5 + 30)
    lis[i] = randreal  # assign to an index
    print(lis)
```

But this is still not very elegant: you first construct a list, and then later modify it. You can improve the code by drawing *10* elements and each time `.append(..)` to the list:

```
lis = []
random.seed(70)
for i in range(0,10):
    randreal = (random.random()*5 + 30)
    lis.append(randreal)  # append to the list
    print(lis)
```

This is already better, but still it is a lot of code, so we can use *list comprehension* to make it more declarative:

```
random.seed(70)
lis = [random.random()*5 + 30 for _ in range(10)]
print(lis)
```

Comment: Or just use a LC to generate the list in one step.

Comment: For the first one, I think you can do: `for i in lis:` since the list contains the indices 0 to 9.

Comment: @ivo: in this case yes. But it would make the code quite unstable: if later one wishes to insert some code between constructing the list and filling it with random numbers it can go wrong. Usually it is better not to make such assumptions on data.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Agreed. Maybe create the list with `lis = [0] * 10` which saves creating the extra range? It pains me to see them both there. :-)